# Dynamically apply filters on Entity Framework's entity using lambda expression

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity, code-first

I need to have a method like this, where I can apply `Where(x =>x. ...)` and `Include(x => x.RelatedEntity)` and `OrderBy(x=>x. ...)` on a given entity.

Something like this:

```
public List<TEntity> ApplyFilter<TEntity>(TEntity entity,
                                          List<filters> filters /* List of filters: 'filters' */)
                                          where TEntity : BaseEntity
    {
        using (var db = new MyDbContext()){
        var query = db.Set<TEntity>().AsQueryable;
   //apply filters to 'query'
        query.include(/*multiple related entities*/);
        query.applyfilters(/*filters*/);

        return query.ToList();
    }
}
```

And I need to pass what I need to be filtered/included as lambda expressions.

**NOTE**: I searched a lot about how I can do it but I really wasn't able to find anything. I'm new to this part of C# / Entity Framework and I really didn't even know what keywords to search for.

Thank you for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to use a LINQ expression

```
    public List<TEntity> ApplyFilter<TEntity>(            
        Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter,
        Expression<Func<TEntity, object>> orderBy,
        params Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>[] includes) where TEntity : BaseEntity
    {
        using (var db = new MyDbContext())
        {
            var query = db.Set<TEntity>().AsQueryable();
            query = query.Where(filter);
            query = query.OrderBy(orderBy);

            if (includes != null)
            {
                foreach (var include in includes)
                {
                    query = query.Include(include);
                }
            }

            return query.ToList();
        }
    }
```

To use the method:

```
        ApplyFilter<TestObject>(
            x => x.Prop1 == "foo", 
            x => x.Prop2,
            x => x.Prop3, x => x.Prop4);
```

Comment: Some of this is accurate, expressions, using the filter in where for example, however, orderby must use something else in order to work. The type needs to be `Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>> orderby` and the use needs to be `query = orderby(query)`.

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
    var result = Repository.PurchaseProposalItem.GetDbSet();

        if (filters.FilterByBrand) result = result.Where(p => p.GS_Product.GS_ProductBrand.PBr_Id == filters.BrandId);
        if (filters.FilterByFamily) result = result.Where(p => p.GS_Product.GS_ProductFamily.PFa_Id == filters.FamilyId);
        if (filters.FilterBySubFamily) result = result.Where(p => p.GS_Product.GS_ProductSubFamily.PSu_Id == filters.SubFamilyId);
        if (filters.FilterByProductType) result = result.Where(p => p.GS_Product.Pro_Type == filters.ProductTypeEnum);

    return result;
```